# Java Generics : Casting a raw type to any reifiable type doesn't generate unchecked cast warning

Tags: java, generics

I have the following question regarding the code below:

```
public class GenericBridgeMethods <T> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List obj = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List <?> l1 = (List<?>) obj; // clause 1
        GenericBridgeMethods <?> g1 = (GenericBridgeMethods<?>) obj; // clause 2
   }

}
```

a. Clause 1 of course won't give an unchecked cast warning
b. Clause 2 also did not give an unchecked cast warning

I noticed that a cast from a raw type (obj) to a ANY reifiable type (like GenericBridgeMethods or GenericBridgeMethods <?>) will not give a unchecked cast warning. If you run this code, a runtime error will occur at clause 2.

Shouldn't the compiler give a warning at clause 2

EDIT 1:

```
    ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // clause 3
    Number n1 = (Number)a1; // clause 4 ERROR
    Comparable c1 = (Comparable)a1; // clause 5

    List l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // clause 6
    Number n2 = (Number)l1; // clause 7
    Comparable c2 = (Comparable)l1; // clause 8
```

Can anyone explain why only clause 4 has error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, first off in `GenericBridgeMethods` as you have defined it, `T` is not a reifiable type.  Reifiable means that the type will be encoded into the class and will be available at runtime.  That is not true of `T`.

Clause 2 does not give a runtime warning because it *is* checked:  There will be a runtime check that `obj` is type-assignable to the `GenericBridgeMethods` type.  Since you've opted for a wildcard as the type parameter, nothing about `T` needs to be checked.

If on the other hand you did something like this:

```
GenericBridgeMethods<String> g1 = (GenericBridgeMethods<String>) obj;
```

that *would* give you an unchecked assignment warning because the fact that `obj` is a `GenericBridgeMethods` of `String`s cannot be checked at runtime.  However, the same warning would appear if you had done this:

```
List<String l1 = (List<String>) obj;
```

### Edit

If you're confused as to why the compiler allows you to try to cast a `List` to a `GenericBridgeMethods`, the answer is because the compiler can't know the entire hierarchy of `GenericBridgeMethods` and its subclasses.  There could be a subclass of `GenericBridgeMethods` that implements `List`, in which case the cast *might* be legitimate.

You *will* however get a compile error if you made `GenericBridgeMethods` a final class (and thus prevented it from having subclasses).  In this case, you will get an inconvertable types error.

Just to show you your question has little to do with reifiable types and generics, take a look at this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   List obj = new ArrayList<Integer>();

   //this is allowed (no warning), even though it will fail at runtime
   CharSequence sequence = (CharSequence) obj; 
}
```

You can explicitly cast `obj` to a `CharSequence` even though *you* know that it will fail at runtime.  The reason is because all the compiler knows is that `obj` is a type of `List`.  Since `List` is an interface, there could be an implementation of `CharSequence` that is also a `List`, and so the cast must be permitted.

*Every* explicit cast carries a degree of possibility that it could fail at runtime.  Otherwise, it would be a redundant cast and the compiler should allow you to omit the explicit cast.

### Edit - Regarding your "edit #1"

```
ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // clause 3
Number n1 = (Number)a1; // clause 4 ERROR
Comparable c1 = (Comparable)a1; // clause 5

List l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // clause 6
Number n2 = (Number)l1; // clause 7
Comparable c2 = (Comparable)l1; // clause 8
```

You are wondering why only "clause 4" does not compile.  I think I explained this already above and in the comments, but I'll go thsough this specific example for you step-by-step.

```
ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // clause 3
Number n1 = (Number)a1; // clause 4 ERROR
```

Casting `a1` to `Number` does not work because `Number` and `ArrayList` are both classes, not interfaces.  Because Java does not allow inheritance from multiple *classes*, for an object to be an instance of both `Number` and `ArrayList`, `Number` would have to be a subclass of `ArrayList` or vice versa.  This is known to not be true at compile time.

```
ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // clause 3
Comparable c1 = (Comparable)a1; // clause 5
```

Since `Comparable` is an interface, a subclass of `ArrayList` might be a `Comparable`.

```
List l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // clause 6
Number n2 = (Number)l1; // clause 7
```

Since `List` is an interface a subclass of `Number` could implement `List`.  The compiler does not know when checking the cast that `l1` holds an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Casting at clause 1&2 is casting to a reifiable type. That was what i meant. Clause 2 DOES give a runtime error! This is the error- java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to GenericBridgeMethod.

Comment: @yapkm01: There's no such thing as a runtime warning in Java libraries.  It of course *fails* because an ArrayList is not a GenericBridgeMethod.  But the compiler can't know that since there could be a subclass of `GenericBridgeMethod` that implements `List`.

Comment: Sorry i changed it to error. Yes. It gives a runtime error. If that is the case, the compiler should have given an unchecked cast warning

Comment: @yap: Unchecked casts have to do with generics.  Your question really has nothing to do with generics; they're clouding the issue.  It's not about reifiability at all.  An unchecked warning means the cast won't actually check the type at runtime; you don't get that here because obviously the type **does** get checked at runtime (otherwise you wouldn't get the `ClassCastException`!!)

Comment: I thought the purpose of the unchecked warning is to warn of potential problem at runtime when comes to type safety. So if clause 2 produces an cast error during runtime, shouldn't there be a warning at clause 2?

Comment: @yapkm01: Type safety in the context of generics.  You can read my last paragraph that I added to my answer, but the *whole point* of explicit casting is to convert from one type to another **when the compiler cannot guarantee it is possible**.  If the compiler could guarantee it is possible, you wouldn't need the explicit cast!  You shouldn't get myriads of warnings when you're using the feature as it's intended to be used.  But if it really bothers you, there are probably static code analysis tools that would flag potentially invalid casts in your code.

Comment: I said it in my answer but I'll reiterate: *unchecked* does not mean "unchecked at compile time", it means "unchecked at *runtime*".

Comment: Thanks. I need sometime to absorb.

Comment: Please see above again under edit 1. Some addition questions related to casting.

Comment: Thanks. I think i roughly got it. Still absorbing. It's very difficult to see things when dealing with casting with generics part of it. It make things so cloudy to see things. Why did those guys in SUN makes it so difficult? Gee ..