# Bogus cast from Class generates error while (bogus) cast from Interface does not?

Tags: java, casting

```
    // Casting of class
    ArrayList a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Number n1 = (Number)a1; // clause 1 Error 
    AdjustmentListener c1 = (AdjustmentListener)a1; // Clause 2 No error
    EventListener c3 = (EventListener)a1; // Clause 3 No error
```

Based on the above, clause 1 has error. Logical. There is no relation between those 2 classes. For clause 2, there is no relation between an arrayList (a class) and the adjustmentlistener interface. Why is there no error?

EDIT 1:

```
    String str1 = new String();
    AdjustmentListener c2 = (AdjustmentListener)str1; // clause 4 compiler error
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Generics : Casting a raw type to any reifiable type doesn't generate unchecked cast warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7676981/java-generics-casting-a-raw-type-to-any-reifiable-type-doesnt-generate-uncheck)

Comment: You were answered in the linked question.

Comment: I am really sure why it has all the down-votes (it is a proper question after the title and question revisions). While the solution *is* in the "duplicate answer", **"this" question is not a duplicate of "that" (Java Generic Cast) question** -- for starters, this is an entirely different *error* and not a *warning*.

Comment: For the poster: Please include the *exact* error message in the question; it will simplify confusion and make the post more search-able.

Comment: Please read my thread carefully. I'm asking why there is no error on clause 2. Hence on my part, there is no error to post. I don't see the answer below as the solution to my question. Something's missing here. It's a very simple question. There is no relation between arraylist and adjustmentlistener. You can check the API. Why is there no error on clause 2?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean compiler error, not runtime error.

Comment: yes but the question has been answer. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for a cast to succeed, there must be some possible implementer of both arguments. Take, for example, the following imaginary class declarations:

```
5: class ComparableArrayList extends ArrayList implements Comparable
7: class NumberList extends Number implements List
8: class ComparableList implements Comparable, List
```

An instance of each would allow the cast to succeed. For clause 4, in order for the cast to work, you would need

```
class NumberArrayList extends ArrayList, Number
```

and Java does not allow multiple inheritance.

**EDIT** for edited question:

In clause 1, there is no *possible* relationship between the classes, because you cannot have a class extend both ArrayList and Number. In clauses 2 and 3, it is possible to *create* a relationship by creating a new class that extends ArrayList and implements AdjustmentListener. Then set a1 to an instance of that class.

Comment: NOW THAT ANSWER MY QUESTION! THANKS. I must not just being able to understand but TO SEE IT! Now here's an example of a good answer which can make me understand. Concise and direct to the point! Thx

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry for being unclear with the first answer.

Comment: How about clause 4? (please refer to edit 1). Same concept as you mentioned above but this time has compilation error.

Comment: No class may extend String and implement AdjustmentListener because String is a final class.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler knows that an ArrayList can never be a Number because in Java you can only inherit from one super class. It can't know if there isn't a type that implements List and inherits from Number ie you could successfully cast a value of the following type to both List and Number:

```
class ListNumber extends Number implements List {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe in this situation you are confused because `a1` is an ArrayList and `l1` is a List [interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28computing%29#Software_interfaces_in_object_oriented_languages) using ArrayList as the [implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_science%29#The_concepts_of_class_interface). List allows you to make the particular cast but ArrayList does not. In this particular case you cannot cast when referencing the implementation but you can when referencing the interface.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a bogus cast from an expression with a *class* result-type the compiler *knows* the cast *can never be valid* and thus it refuses to compile with a compile-time error. (Changing what a class extends or implements is a breaking-change: to avoid odd run-time exceptions code should be re-compiled against the new class structure.)

However, when casting from an expression with an *interface* result-type the compiler *cannot* (normally) determine that the cast will never be valid (but consider `final` types); as such there is no compile error. There will, however, be a run-time exception when the bogus cast is attempted.

Imagine this small compilable example (note that *generics are unrelated to the post*):

```
interface I {}
class A implements I {}
class B {}
// Imagine class BB is defined as such later.
//class BB extends B implements I {}
final class C {}

public class test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        // ERROR: "Cannot cast from A to B"
        // Compiler knows that B is not a super-type of A.
        B b1 = (B)(new A());
        // Valid: A implements I
        I i = (I)(new A());
        // RUNTIME EXCEPTION: Compiles, but will fail at run-time
        // as B is not a super-type of A. The compiler allows
        // this because B could have a sub-type (BB) which
        // implements the interface (I) and the cast from a
        // sub-type (BB) to a super-type (B) is valid.
        B b2 = (B)i;
        // ERROR: Cannot cast from I to C
        // Compiler knows C cannot have a sub-type which implements
        // the interface (I) and thus it can reject the program.
        // (Note that C is a final class and cannot be extended.)
        C c = (C)i;
        // Valid (when defining BB): no run-time exception as B is
        // is a super-type of BB.
        //B b3 = (B)(I)(new BB());
    }
}
```

Happy coding.